# How to include a PHP generated XML file into flash vars, while ALSO passing through the current php functions into it?

Tags: php, xml, include, flash

Hello **Given situation**: In `webpage.php` the flashscript is calling a flash script with a flashvar: the playlist file which is a PHP generated XML file: `playlist.php`, it does that well so long as there are no extra functions in there. Now, in that `XML-format` playlistfile there needs to be a special function, besides the usual `echo("");`, namely the very special `echo __("");` function that is already declared in `webpage.php` which needs to do something with the paragraphs residing within that xml file.

**However**, currently the retrieved file misses the function `echo __();`and says ***"no such function declared in that xml-format [playlist.php] file"***. The php functions that are currently included at the very top of `webpage.php` somehow do not pass-through-the necessary functions into the playlist file for it to recognise how to handle it, in order for that playlist to get those necessary functions working.

Apparently these are not passed through automatically/properly when residing in the flashvars?? Cause the `echo __("");` works fine when called within `webpage.php` or via a normal php `include("");` if those functions are in a different php file. But not working from the `playlist.php` file.

Any ideas why/what is going on here?
I appreciate your clues for this prob +1. Thanks very much.

---

**WEBPAGE.PHP** the webpage, has at the top an include with functions:

```
<?php include (functions.php); ?> 
//  function that know what to do with echo __("paragraph")
```

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    run(
      'play', 'true',
      'loop', 'true',
      'flashvars', 'xmlFile=/incl/playlist.php',    // <<<< !!
      'wmode', 'transparent',
      'allowScriptAccess','sameDomain',
    );
</script>

<noscript>
   <object classid="blabla">
   <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
   <param name="movie" value="/movies/movie.swf" />
   <param name="flashvars" value="xmlFile=/incl/playlist.php" />  // <<< !!
   <embed src="/movies/movies.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"/>
   </object>
</noscript>
```

---

**PLAYLIST.PHP** The PHP generated XML file which is retrieved into the webpage as flash variable (see above)

```
<?php
echo ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>');
echo ('<songs>');
    echo ('<song version="1. "') . __("boom blue blow bell bowl") . ('/>');
    echo ('<song version="2. "') . __("ball bail beam bike base") . ('/>');
echo ('</songs>');
?>
```

Comment: You're not understanding how this works. `webpage.php` is executed and its output sent to the browser, with the literal string `'xmlFile=/incl/playlist.php'` included in its output. The client then makes a second completely independent request for that file, which must include all the server-side files required to run independent of `webpage.php`. This is not at all the same as `webpage.php` including `playlist.php` server-side via `include` or `require`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you pass the path to playlist.php to the Flash Player, which then connects to the server to call the actual php page.  If that is true, you must include the __() function into the playlist.php as well, or otherwise it can't be called.

Comment: Thanks WeltRaumPirat, yes. But the function has already been called (consuming kbytes , cpu etc) why call it again? You brought me to an idea. is it possible to for example including it as if it were a `$string = include("playlist.php");` and then somehow putting this `$string` output into that flashvar?? if yes, how to do this? (will try now, excitiinggggg)

Comment: You need to understand that you have two php pages: One that embeds the flash plugin, and one that is called from WITHIN the flash movie, which then generates the playlist.  What you are passing on through flashvars is not an actual playlist, but the path to where the flash player can find that second page.  Actually, the function isn't even called in webpage.php, unless you have some more code you haven't shown us here.  You can remove the include from there - it doesn't do anything.

Comment: yeah true, sofar no results... perhaps only way is then to again include the functions into that php generated xml file, see what happens. ( sofar it complains about wrong paths but will try to see what if thats fixed)

Comment: Don't do that.  Your Flash app will not load the XML properly. If it complains about wrong paths, you probably should look into that.

Comment: When i include the functions at the top of the playlist.php, then everything WORKS, however, isn't it waste of bandwith to load same indlude file twice?????? not what i would call an elegant solution...

Comment: No it isn't - php is a pre_processor.  It is executed on the server and sends only the rendered output to the browser.  All it "wastes" is a tiny fraction of a second to load the file from the server's hard drive. Plus, you don't need the include in the other page, as I've said before.

Comment: @Sam Including the functions twice in both files is the correct way to do it, regardless of whether you feel it is elegant.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure it's ok to give swf a relative url to server script

Comment: Of course it is.  Only it will be relative to the path of the swf file.

Comment: @ weltraumpirat : i've always provided absolute links and it was working ok

Comment: Well, absolute paths and relative paths are both okay anywhere else in your html. Why should it be different here?

Comment: @ weltraumpirat : when i met such situations the reason was always rather stupid - i usually started with checking and changing embed code and it often helped

Comment: Have the feeling that its nothing to do with relative or absolute paths: both work fine when set properly.